# creating and passing block to method not working in objective-c

Tags: ios, objective-c, objective-c-blocks

This is my first time trying to create a block. Will someone please correct the syntax for me? Basically, I have a method that accepts a block and executes it. The block itself takes a parameter. So, the method would do some work, then call the given block with a parameter.

Here is where I am calling the method:

```
    //The method takes an image URL and a block
    [self loadImageFromUrl:splashUrl addImageToViewWithBock:^(UIImage *image){
        if (image) {
            UIImageView *bkgIV = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:image];
            [self.tableView setBackgroundView:bkgIV];
        }
    }];
```

Here is the method itself:

```
-(void)loadImageFromUrl:imageUrl addImageToViewWithBock:imageBlock
{
    NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:imageUrl];
    NSURLSessionConfiguration *config=[NSURLSessionConfiguration ephemeralSessionConfiguration];
    NSURLSession *session = [NSURLSession sessionWithConfiguration:config];
    NSURLSessionDownloadTask *task =
    [session downloadTaskWithRequest:request
                   completionHandler:^(NSURL *localfile, NSURLResponse *response, NSError *error) {
                       if (!error) {
                           if ([request.URL isEqual:imageUrl]) {//check in case things have changed somehow
                               UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:localfile]];
                               dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), imageBlock(image));
                           }
                       }
                   }];
    [task resume];
}

//Here the compiler says that imageBock is not a block.
```

Comment: Uh… dude… your implementation doesn't declare any types for the arguments it takes.

Comment: @jeffamaphone Nah… [goshdarnblocksyntax.com](http://goshdarnblocksyntax.com)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two things:

1) You didn't declare the types of the parameters of your `-loadImageFromUrl:addImageToViewWithBock:` method. The compiler assumes they are of type `id`. You want something like:

```
-(void)loadImageFromUrl:(NSURL*)imageUrl addImageToViewWithBock:(void (^)(UIImage*))imageBlock
```

2) In your call to `dispatch_async()`, you are not passing a new block. You have invoked the block that was passed in, but that doesn't produce a new block. You probably just want to surround that invocation in a block of its own, like:

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{ imageBlock(image); });
```

Comment: Thanks. I was so nervous about creating the block I forgot to declare the types. I fix that but the code is still not working so I am looking to see what else might be wrong: maybe some other part of my code.

Comment: So, there are no more compiler errors, just undesirable runtime behavior?

Answer (score 0):

Your method declaration doesn't show that it's a block, or that the URL is a URL/String, etc.
Where do you show the data types for the arguments?

Should be something like:

```
-(void)loadImageFromUrl:(NSURL*)imageUrl addImageToViewWithBock:(^)imageBlock {}
```